# SyntaxError: invalid syntax (unknown token [ ])

Tags: python, while, token, syntax, counter

Пока что учу циклы и сделал примерный код, чтобы понять как оно работает:

```python
counter = 0

while counter < 15:
  print(counter)
  counter = counter + 1
else:
  print("end")
```

Когда запускаю код выводит ошибку:

```console
File <string>, line 3
     print(counter)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (unknown token [ ])
```

Смотрел много видео и читал форумы но до сих пор не могу понять что с этим делать.

Comment: У вас в отступах второй пробел - не пробел, а символ с кодом `a0`:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7XHm.png Отступы должны быть или обычными пробелами, или табами. Лучше пробелами.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    counter = 0

while counter < 15:
  print(counter)
  counter = counter + 1
else:
  print("end")
```

видимо отступ забыли в 3 строке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Сам код корректный, у вас проблема с отступами, с точки зрения интерпретатора количество пробелов должно быть одинаковым внутри одного блока, но среди Python-разработчиков принято использовать четыре пробела, либо одну табуляцию.

```
counter = 0

while counter < 15:
    print(counter)
    counter = counter + 1
else:
    print("end")
```

Comment: Не совсем так. 4 пробела следует использовать потому что все используют 4 пробела. С точки зрения интерпретатора ничто не мешает использовать 2 пробела, один пробел или 5. Главное чтобы их количество было равным после `while`. Можно даже так: после `while` поставить по 5 пробелов, а после `else` 3, код отработает, и отработает правильно, но будет слабо читаем. Поэтому принято ставить либо 4 пробела, либо одну табуляцию.

Comment: @DiMithras спасибо! это полезная информация, я о таком не знал. Добавил к ответу.